# Eclipse exported Runnable Jar fails througing java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception

Tags: java, eclipse

This problem is a famous one and there are many similar questions but no solution helped me. So please, don't mark my question as duplicate.

I developed a small application in Java that uses external dlls. Everything seems to be working fine in eclipse but once I export to runnable jar and run using `java -jar myapplication.jar`, it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Testing.dal.LoggingAccess.__LoggingAccess0(Lnet/sf/jni4net/inj/IClrProxy;Ljava/lang/String;)V
        at Testing.dal.LoggingAccess.__LoggingAccess0(Native Method)
        at Testing.dal.LoggingAccess.<init>(LoggingAccess.java:25)
        at Program.listItems(Program.java:32)
        at Program.main(Program.java:27)
```

I have tried to do almost all what is suggested in other answers but unfortunately nothing worked for me. 
I tried to set `java.library.path`, but I don't know if i'm doing it correctly. I'm not a java developer and java world is totally new to me. So I may be doing it in the wrong way. 
It would be great if you can give me any hint on how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem myself.

The needed library was in the correct place but I had to reference it in the java project. The problem is that i don't want to play around with Path (environment variables) or copy the libraries to the system32 folder as suggested in many posts. Thats why i added `System.Laod(new java.io.File("path to the dll").getAbsolutePath())` at the beginning of the main method.

Many recommended to mention the library name without .dll extension, but for me it worked only with .dll. Moreover, I had to load not only the needed library but also all the libraries that my library depends on. For example: my library depends on `EntityFramework.dll`, so i had to include this line in the main method:

```
System.load(new java.io.File("path/EntityFramework.dll").getAbsolutePath());
```

After exporting the project into a runnable jar file and tested from the cmd with statement `java -jar exported-file.jar`, I was then able to see the outputs correctly in the console. I just posted this answer in case someone is facing such an error and searching a solution.